# Method not returning

Tags: java, return

```
public class ListaLojas {

  private HashMap<String, Loja> lojas;
  TreeMap<Integer, Loja> copy = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

  public ListaLojas(){
    lojas = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public HashMap getLojas(){
    return lojas;
  }
}

public class Aplicacao{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListaLojas listL = new ListaLojas();
      listL.putLoja("loja1", l1);
      listL.putLoja("loja2", l2);
      listL.putLoja("loja3", l3);
      listL.putLoja("loja4", l4);
      listL.putLoja("loja5", l5);
      listL.putLoja("loja6", l6);
      listL.getLojas();
    }
}
```

When I run it, it returns nothing. I am using NetBeans and there are no syntax errors.

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: damn youre right, sorry for wasting you time

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you're never printing *anything*. So just replace the line:

```
listL.getLojas();
```

with following:

```
System.out.println(listL.getLojas());
```

Which prints every element consecutively